# Is it possible to set up shortcuts in Xcode to jump to specific files?

Tags: keyboard, applications, xcode, shortcut

Say I want to jump to my Storyboard file, or my Images.xcassets file. Is there a way to set up a keyboard shortcut to be able to jump to it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not shortcut, is more like a quick way to open files. Typing <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> lets you type the name of the file you want to open.

Comment: Still some more typing involved than I would like, as I have to search for the file.

Comment: Sorry then, does not exist other way to do it.